# iOS - UIView of same small width does not layout on smaller devices

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have an UIView that is defined below -

```
private let verticalSeparatorLine: UIView = {
   let view = UIView()
   view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   view.alpha = 0.94
   view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
   return view
}()
```

This is how I add it to the viewcontroller's view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addTestView()
}

private func addTestView() {

    view.addSubview(verticalSeparatorLine)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        verticalSeparatorLine.centerX.constraint(to: view.centerX),
        verticalSeparatorLine.bottomAnchor.constraint(to: view.bottomAnchor),
        verticalSeparatorLine.widthAnchor.constraint(0.3),
        verticalSeparatorLine.heightAnchor.constraint(70)
    ])
}
```

If I add this verticalSeparatorLine to the ViewController's view in a larger device like iPhone X, the view lays out as expected. In smaller devices the view's width is zero. If I increase the width to say 2, it appears on both the devices.

[image: iPhone X with View]
[image: 0.33 Width]
[image: iPhone 7]
[image: 0.0 Width iPhone 7]

Am I missing something?

**Update**: 
If I replace with `leadingAnchor`, `verticalSeparatorLine` is visible with a width of 0.5.

`verticalSeparatorLine.leadingAnchor.constraint(to: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),`

Comment: I faced this problem before, after search & try many ways, finally my solution is using image here ^_^!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the device's resolution, if UIScreen.main.scale == 2 means you set width 1 equals to 2 pixel's width, so 0.3(0.6pixel) can't be displayed, but in scale3 device, 0.33 just equals to 1 pixel.